# Where's the Analytics / UI to PowerShell DSC?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, analytics, orchestration, dsc

Even using pull mode for Powershell DSC, it doesn't seem there's an easy way to visualise which machines are in which states and which machines are in the process of correcting themselves to the desired state (i.e. still installing stuff / rebooting).

I feel like I'm missing something. Is some website meant to go over the top and provide this visibility? Please tell me *someone* has plugged this gap already - it's been over a year now. We could start building from this point but I was hoping something was already in this space?

I've had a look at guardrail and while it seems a pretty cool product, it doesn't focus on the orchestration side of deployment.

This is about as specific as I can make this question - I know a lot of other people are keen to hear your answers to this. Please don't mark it as vague or subjective right away :-)

Comment: why is this on hold in answered the question and had a link to a beta version of the software that provided a gui to do DSC??

Answer (score 2):

You're not alone and you're not missing anything. There's no GUI for this right now (there's barely a not-GUI).

Did you deploy a DSC Compliance Server along with the pull server?

If so, you can query it to retrieve useful information. There is no dashboard or interface for it at this time.

There may be third party products available but I'm not aware of any. Powershell v5 is supposed to have a lot of improvements to DSC so it may be worth waiting.

Since [Chef can use DSC resources](https://www.getchef.com/solutions/windows/#dsc) (and it seems [Puppet support is here](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/msutter/dsc) or on its way), many people may choose to go with one of those since the tooling is much more mature.

### Further Reading

- [Powershell.org - DSC Compliance Server: What's the Deal?](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/powershell-dsc-compliance-server-whats-the-deal/)
- [How to retrieve node information from DSC pull server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/05/29/how-to-retrieve-node-information-from-pull-server.aspx)